# Regular Expression for URL matching not working in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, xcode

I found a PHP regular expression to detect a Web URL:

```
$url_pattern = '/((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#])*/';
```

This regular expression can match URLs like those below:

```
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
google.com
```

Now, I am trying to use it in *Objective-C* as:

```
NSString * expression = @"/((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#])*/";
NSRegularExpression * regularExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSInteger numberOfMatches = [regularExp numberOfMatchesInString:@"www.google.com" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, URLString.length)];

if (numberOfMatches >= 1)
{
    return @"webURL";
}
else
{
    return @"searchEngine";
}
```

It is not detecting any kind of URL. I tested it at [regexr.com](http://regexr.com).

Comment: Remove delimiters, use double slashes where necessary. `NSString * expression = @"(?:(?:http|https)://)?[a-zA-Z0-9./\\?:@\\-_=#]+\\.([a-zA-Z0-9./\\?:@\\-_=#])*";`. It can even be contracted to `NSString *pattern = @"(?:(?:http|https)://)?[\\w./\\?:@=#-]+\\.([\\w./\\?:@=#-])*";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bear in mind that the PHP regex is usually used within delimiters that should be removed when using such regex patterns in Objective C. Also, we do not have to escape every non-word character inside a character class (only a hyphen), but outside a character class, you must double-escape special characters.

So, use

```
NSString *pattern = @"(?:(?:http|https)://)?[a-zA-Z0-9./?:@\\-_=#]+\\.([a-zA-Z0-9./?:@\\-_=#])*";
```

Or, you can even contract to

```
NSString *pattern = @"(?:(?:http|https)://)?[\\w./?:@=#-]+\\.([\\w./?:@=#-])*";
```

See the hyphen at the end of character class does not need escaping.

See [CodingGround demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUGJFUUJZM1JVZkE)

Comment: Just note that regex101.com or regexr.com can just give you a gist of what you can acheive with your regex, but you will still have to "adjust" the regex to the Objective C syntax and capabilities according to the [Objective C Regex documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW26)

Answer (score 0):

check this one :

NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http|https)://((\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+(\.|/)+";

I am using this one in my app

Answer (score 0):

Please Try following code for validate URL

```
- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) stringURL {
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:stringURL];
}
```